# Priority of API Gateway routes not working as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-routes.html),

```
API Gateway selects the route with the most-specific match, using the following priorities:

1.  Full match for a route and method.

2.  Match for a route and method with a greedy path variable ({proxy+}).

3.  The $default route.
```

And our API Gateway looks like this:
[image]

I would expect this to go to the `/auth` lambda function:

`curl -X POST --data @auth.json https://XYZ.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/MY-stage/auth`

But instead, the request is being intercepted by the `/{entity}` lambda function.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: have you found any solution for your problem ? dealing with same thing.. if you can help here.

Comment: @Vicky, we were never able to figure this out.  We were forced to do this: leave /auth alone, but change /{entity} to /api/{entity}.  That way, requests to /auth were intercepted correctly, and all other /api/* were caputured too.  It's not ideal at all, but that was our workaround :( Stinks, I know.

Comment: have you tried using test feature in aws api gateway itself? it provides all the information about the request and the test logs have the actual endpoint for which the request is made